# A combinatorial game theory problem

Tags: combinatorics

In details, there are four bishops on a chessboard in two pairs. In each pair they sit in orthogonally adjacent squares. How many positions can there be to place the two pairs on the chessboard without capturing any of the pair by any of another pair?

(There are two pairs of bishops. Bishops in the same pair are friends. But bishops of the different pairs are enemies. And in this problem we have to determine the arrangements of the four bishops such that none can be captured.)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Your question is not that clear. On one hand you say the bishops are of the same colour, on the other hand, you talk about bishops capturing each other. Also, do you mean that bishops can not capture each other in the immediate next move? If so, whose move is it next?

Comment: Probably the OP means : How many possibilities are there to place $4$ bishops on a $n\times n$-board, such that no two of them cover each other (are placed on some common diagonal) ?

Comment: There are two pairs of bishops. bishops in the same pair are friends. so they don't capture each other. So they can be captured. But bishops of the different pairs are enemies. But all 4 bishops are in the same shape and colors. And in this problem we have to determine the arrangements of the four bishops such that none can be captured.

Comment: What do you mean by "*vicinal squares*"? Does that cover diagonally adjacent, orthogonally adjacent, or both? And why do you call this a combinatorial game theory problem? It seems to be a single combinatorial question.

Comment: orthogonally adjacent

Comment: @SummitRoy: I edited your question based on your responses to the comments. Let me know if I changed the meaning.

Comment: How to-I would just write a program t count them.  Step through the white squares on the board as locations for one white bishop.  Then step through the two to four black squares neighboring as locations for the other white bishop.  Step through the remaining white squares as locations for the first black bishop and make sure it cannot be attacked.  Then check the two to four neighboring black squares for attack.